# Pass parameters to Navigation Factory

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I want to create Categories menu from database records, but limit the menu items with current category and it's subcategories (like on Walmart.com). The catch is how to access current category in Navigation Factory where I create the pages for the menu?

Navigation factory:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class CategoriesMenu extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getPages(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
    if (null === $this->pages) {
        $em = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        // here I need to know the current category

        $categories = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Category')->getRootCategories();

        $nav = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $page = array(
           'label' => $category->getName(),
           'route' => 'category',
           'params' => array(
               'category_path' => $category->getUrlName(),
            ),
           'pages' => array(),
           );
           $nav[] = $page;
        }
        $configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()] = $nav;

        $application = $serviceLocator->get('Application');
        $routeMatch  = $application->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        $router      = $application->getMvcEvent()->getRouter();
        $pages       = $this->getPagesFromConfig($configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()]);

        $this->pages = $this->injectComponents($pages, $routeMatch, $router);
    }
    return $this->pages;
    }
}
```

Categories menu factory:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class CategoriesMenuFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getName()
    {
    return 'categoriesmenu';
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
    $navigation = new CategoriesMenu();
    return $navigation->createService($serviceLocator);
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'categoriesmenu' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\CategoriesMenuFactory',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Your 'current category', if it is a route parameter, would be within the route match object. You should be able to access it via `$routeMatch->getParam('category')`. If it is a GET or POST you can fetch it from the request instance.

Comment: Thanks, I found the way with getting this parameter from route, but ideally I'd like to pass it from controller to the navigation, because now I have to load the category object twice, in controller and in navigation factory.